# What is the benefit of tagged PDF in comparison with logical PDF in reflowing

Tags: pdf, tags, reflow

I'm making a PDF viewer and try to make reflowing.
I read the PDF Reference 1.7

http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf

When I read the section "Logical Structure" (10.6), I think it's sufficient to make reflowing PDF. Because I can extract each chapter, each heading, each paragraph with layout, I can put them in xml to present as web displaying with reflowing by javascript.

Then I read the section "Tagged PDF" (10.7), it says it support reflowing, I don't recognize the different benefit here in comparison with "Logical Structure". Can anyone explain me?

Many thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2):

They are both related, the logical structure is a tree at document level where each node may (or may not) have a reference to a marked-content (tag) in a page. Marked-content or tags is what will really tell you wich part of a page is a paragraph, or a figure, or something else. The logical structure tree is just the structure of the document, but using that alone you will not be able to process the content of each page.

Comment: Many thanks! I have one more question: I read somewhere, they say about "auto-tagging", can you explain more?